# Issues with Google Play Closed and Internal Testing Tracks

Tags: testing, google-play, google-play-console

I recently have finished my first app, and I am planning to release it to the Google Play Store. To do this, I would like to test on a testing track first.

I created a simple release with my APK on an internal testing track, and shared it with some testers. The only URL I see is the "Join on the web" link as seen below.
[image: It does say it is available to all testers]
[image: I also thought there was supposed to be some sort of Opt-Out link which I do not see here]

If I try to join with that link on my laptop, I get the error following page.
[image]
After I click the link to download the app, I get a "URL not found" error.
[image]
When I try to do the same thing on my Android phone. It links to the play store but then just loads forever. This is the first publication of my app (I heard it could take 48 hours) but it has almost been three days since I first did this.

I also tried working with a closed test track instead. or the past couple of days, the closed testing track link has also been giving me similar errors. This one is still showing "Being reviewed". Is there a typical amount of time it takes for it to be reviewed by Google?

Does anyone have any proposed solutions to get either track working or an alternative to test an Android app?

Comment: Was that really a review matter? I face the same problem and still waiting.

Comment: I am still waiting (nothing has changed since posting). I hope it is a review problem (Google reviews do seem to be taking a bit longer during this COVID time). Currently, I have working on testing using Microsoft App Center for faster results.

Comment: @arjun30 same problem.how long did it take?

Comment: @Zima It took over a week before it worked for me. 

In the meantime, I used Microsoft App center. It is easy to use, and there is no wait time. If it needs to be tested on Google Play, in my experience, the open tracks (and sometimes the closed ones) get approved faster than the internal one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might take some time for the reviews specially for the first release.
It has happend for me sometimes within a day and sometimes took 2-3 days.

The approval time really depends on a lot of  factors.

For testing purposes you can also use
[MS - appcenter](https://appcenter.ms/)  for distribution of builds to tester.

The free subscription gives unlimited testers and distributions.
This is very easy to set up as well